# Azure ADB2C multiple Web APIs authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c

My scenario is related to the authentication of two or more web APIs from the same MVC Web App in which ADB2C is configured.

I have created two web apis in Azure ADB2C and granted permissions of both the web apis into ADB2C MVC web app. However whenever I tried to obtain the access token, it is giving me the access token for one web api but not giving the access token for the second one.

I want to know whether this scenario is possible in ADB2C or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One access token could be used to access by one resource(web api) . If you want another resource's access token , you can use refresh token(if exists) to get the new token :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token

If using [MSAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) ,after initial token acquisition , you can invoke `AcquireTokenSilent`, asking for the api scopes you need :

```
// Retrieve the token with the specified scopes
var scope = AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes.Split(' ');
string signedInUserID = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

IConfidentialClientApplication cca =
ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(AzureAdB2COptions.RedirectUri)
    .WithClientSecret(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientSecret)
    .WithB2CAuthority(AzureAdB2COptions.Authority)
    .Build();
new MSALStaticCache(signedInUserID, this.HttpContext).EnablePersistence(cca.UserTokenCache);

var accounts = await cca.GetAccountsAsync();
AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilent(scope, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

MSAL will look up the cache and return any cached token which match with the requirement. If such access tokens are expired or no suitable access tokens are present, but there is an associated refresh token, MSAL will automatically use that to get a new access token and return it transparently.

You can click [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp) for code sample .

Comment: Hi Nan, I tried exactly what you suggested here. But when i tried to acquire token by passing the scope of another web api, it is not giving me the access token. It is coming as null.

Comment: Do you successfully get access token + refresh token for the first resource .

Comment: Yes. I successfully got the access token & refresh token for the first web api.

Comment: If you swap the scopes around, can you still get an access token for one?

Comment: Did you consent for both resource ? And try to use fiddler to trace the request to check whether any problem occurs .

Comment: @Jas yes if i swapped the scopes, i still get an access token for only one resource.

Comment: @Nan yes I provided the consent for both the scopes in MVC web app from the Azure portal. I also tried fiddler to intercept the request but no luck. Didn't find anything. Also you can remove your above solution because it is not taking me anywhere.

Comment: I just want to know whether this kind of scenario is possible in ADB2C or not? Because Microsoft documentation doesn't include such scenarios. If it is possible then how?

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava , you can directly use rest api with [code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) instead of .net sdk to trace the problem . Use refresh token is the traditional way to renew access token no matter in Azure AD or B2C .

Comment: @Nan I tried what you proposed as well but no luck. I just want to know there is no straight forward way to achieve this scenario? This is the most common scenario I guess.

Comment: So what is the response when using refresh token to renew access token in fiddler or postman ?

Comment: @Nan it gives me back the access token again but with extended life time for the same web api resource but not for another one.

Comment: Do you set scope to another resource's scope ?

Comment: @Nan yes I did. But then it returned null.

Comment: What is the web response when you put the second scope in the request? Try trace it with Fiddler. This answer should be working by the way.

Comment: @JasSuri When I put a second scope in the request, it gives me back the access token for second scope but again token for the first scope was empty.

Comment: You can only request for one resource at a time. Your answer suggests you are trying both scopes to different resources in one request, which won’t work.